# Can't start Windows 7

Tags: boot, windows-7

I get this error message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcb

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I need the Windows disk, but I do not have it.

I need to fix this through Ubuntu.

I tried a Windows recovery disk, but it did not recognize it.

Ubuntu is 12.04 desktop on bootable flash drive.

Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium.

Comment: "Why i posted on askUbuntu? -banned from superuser and have to fix with ubuntu." I don't see the question there on your user account. It would still be there as closed, but it isn't listed. Or is this http://superuser.com/q/616963/157409 ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Windows-specific boot error. The fact that you claim to be banned on SuperUser doesn't make it on-topic here, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only fixable by using a Windows recovery DVD (essentially your bootloader configuration has been corrupted), and so wouldn't be on-topic for AskUbuntu.

However, because I'm a nice guy, I'll point you in the right direction. You'll need to [download a Windows 7 ISO](http://www.w7forums.com/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads-t12325.html) (perfectly legally, as long as you're using it in conjunction with a legal licence) and run the Startup Repair option.

If burning to DVD doesn't work for you, and you have access to another Windows PC, you can use the [Windows 7 USB Installer Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to create a bootable USB installer.

Comment: if i use "Windows 7 USB Installer Tool" would i be able to boot would it be just a installer or an actual bootable drive?

Comment: It would be a USB version of a Windows 7 install DVD, it wouldn't be a "live" bootable Windows environment. You should, however, be able to use the Startup Repair functionality to recover your Windows installation to a bootable state. Details here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm

Comment: I know this question is outdated at this point but you are able to create a Windows 7 bootable usb drive as described by this question on serverfault: [How to make Windows 7 USB flash install media from Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux).